# Holographic derivation of correlations functions in $\text{AdS}_3$/$\text{CFT}_2$

Tags: quantum-gravity, correlation-functions, ads-cft, wess-zumino-witten

**Intro**

I am interested in finding the correlations functions $\langle A^{a_1}_z(z_1) \cdots A^{a_k}_z(z_k) \rangle$ in the frame of $\text{AdS}_3$/$\text{CFT}_2$ correspondance for 3D gravity and two chiral Wess-Zumino-Witten ($\chi \text{WZW}$) models. Indeed, $\text{AdS}_3$ gravity is given by the difference between two Chern-Simons ($\text{CS}$), and it is known that a holographic principle holds for $\text{CS}/\text{WZW}$.

I will write by $A^{\pm,a}_z$ the gauge field $\omega^a_z\pm\sqrt{\Lambda}e^a_z$, where $\omega$ is the dualized spin connection and $e$ the dreibein. The components of interest are $A_z$ and $A_\overline{z}$ because I chose to integrate over $A_t$ in the partition function to enforce the Gauss constraint.

The AdS/CFT statement is:
\begin{equation}
Z^\text{CS}[A_z|_{\partial}]=\left\langle e^{i\int d^2z\,\text{Tr}[A_z\overline{\mathcal{J}}]} \right\rangle_\text{$\chi$WZW},\,\,\,\overline{\mathcal{J}}\propto G^{-1}\overline{\partial}G \tag{1}
\end{equation}
$A_z|_{\partial}$ is the gauge field on the conformal boundary.

Now, the $\text{CS}$ action on the left-hand side can be reduced to a $\text{WZW}$ action too, see appendix B.1 of [Li, Toumbas, and Troost: *Liouville Quantum Gravity*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.06501) for example. So upon introducing the correct boundary term in the $\text{CS}$ action, we can write (1) as:
\begin{equation}
\int_{A_z|_\partial = A_z}\mathcal{D}A^+\mathcal{D}A^-\,e^{i(S^\text{$\chi$WZW}[A_z^+]-S^\text{$\chi$WZW}[A_z^-])}=\prod_{i=+,-}\left\langle e^{i\int d^2z\,\text{Tr}[A^i_z\overline{\mathcal{J}}]} \right\rangle_\text{$\chi$WZW} \tag{2}
\end{equation}
Thanks to the Brown-Henneaux boundary conditions, the kinetic part of the $S^\text{$\chi$WZW}$ should contain a term of the form:
\begin{equation}
S^\text{$\chi$WZW} \ni \int_\partial d^2z\,\text{Tr}[(H^{-1}\partial H)^2]\stackrel{\text{Brown-Henneaux}}{=}\int_\partial d^2z\,\text{Tr}[A_z A_z] \tag{3}
\end{equation}

**Problem**

My calculations are for a $\text{dS}/\text{CFT}$ but I chose to introduce the AdS correspondence because it is, I think, better understood; and a sketch of my reasoning to be clear. My problem is the following: From (3), I can calculate the two-point correlation function $\langle A^a_z(x) A^b_z(y) \rangle$ from the left-hand side of (2). But it appears that since the Wess-Zumino term is a determinant, the structure constants cannot be brought in the three-point correlation function. Indeed, a determinant is anti-symmetric, and the product of functional derivatives is symmetric.

**Question**

I managed to find all the correlation functions by saying that le right-hand side of (2) is a wave functional $\Psi$ obeying $F^\pm\Psi[A_z]=0$, where $F^\pm$ is the gauge curvature operator of the gauge field $A^\pm$. Since we have $[A_\overline{z}(x),A_z(y)]\sim \delta^{(2)}(x-y)$, we can deduce that, by first quantization:
\begin{equation}
A_\overline{z} \sim \frac{\delta}{\delta A_z} \tag{4}
\end{equation}
To me, this means that we should have an Operator-Product-Expansion (OPE) for the functional derivatives too. So something like:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta}{\delta A^a_z(x)}\frac{\delta}{\delta A^b_z(y)} \sim \frac{k\delta^{ab}}{(x-y)^2}+i\frac{f^{abc}}{x-y}\frac{\delta}{\delta A^c_z(y)} \tag{5}
\end{equation}
This could completely resolve my problem but I didn't see anywhere this OPE for functional derivative operators.

So my question is: Is this equality (5) correct in the light of Chern-Simons quantization and reduction of the CS model to a WZW one? If not, how does one recover the correlation functions from le AdS side?